# Parsing a large XML file, crashing IIS

Tags: php, xml, iis

I have a large XML file which I like to read into PHP to later inject into MySQL.

I have tried several technics to read this XML file, both compressed sourced and uncompressed.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('compress.zlib://CategoryFeaturesList.xml.gz');
```

This results in a IIS crash. Tried it on XAMPP, same thing.

Also tried this:

```
$xmlfile = 'compress.zlib://CategoryFeaturesList.xml.gz';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlfile);
```

Could anyone help me out, on how to parse this specific XML file?

Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I forgot a link to the file. http://pos.admin-x.com/CategoryFeaturesList.xml.gz

Comment: Use read method untill find desired item